# Cassandra cluster simple query error

Tags: cassandra, debian, cluster-computing, cql

I'm learning Cassandra and I have a problem. I have a cluster with 2 computers (node A and node B). On a computer I can create new users and keyspaces and on the other one I can use this users and keyspaces. But if i create a new table on any of these computers (inside cassandra, on a keyspace), i can't see this new table with a simple query statement like `SELECT * FROM table` or `SELECT * FROM keyspace.table`. Cassandra displays this error "`ServerError: <ErrorMessage code=0000 [Server error] message='java.lang.AssertionError">`"

if i use nodetool status on the node A (node+seeder) displays an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No nodes present in the cluster. Has this node finished startin up?
```

but if i use nodetool status on the node B (only node), displays a node: the node B.

Keyspace stamement:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
```

Cassandra 3.2 is installed on Debian

What can i do? any ideas? I can't fix it

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide with your keyspace definition?  Also, post the output of `nodetool status`.

Comment: I edit the question, what can i do?